# generate a random string with with exactly 6 digits (show first 0)

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a string with exactly 6 random numbers in it. My current code:

```
$test = sprintf('%6d', rand(1, 1000000));
```

With this code I get a string that sometimes has an empty value at the beginning like `" 53280"`. I would want to have it produce `"053280"` in that case. How to achieve this?

Comment: just go with sprintf('%06d', rand(1, 1000000)); you are just missing the left leading zero on the formatting string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `0` in your conversion specification to indicate that you want zero-padding:

```
$test = sprintf('%06d', rand(1, 1000000));
//                ^-- here
```

The conversion specifications are documented on [the `sprintf` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace the empty character with 0.

```
$test = str_replace(" ", "0", sprintf('%6d', rand(1, 1000000)));
```

Comment: Those people who minus grade this answer. The question was:"With this code I get a string that sometimes has an empty value at the beginning like " 53280". I would want to have it produce "053280" in that case. How to achieve this? " Straightforward way to resolve this is to replace the predicted empty characters with 0.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this method. It does work, I tested it out.

Comment: I know it does work but don't understand some people who downgrade to get their answers on top!

Comment: Don't know either, but thank you for helping me out!

Comment: No, I did not mean to blame on you guys. I was talking about in general people do that. People who downgrade at least should comment on their reason. It shouldn't be click and go function.

Comment: I downvoted because while it may work it isn’t what I would consider idiomatic. I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `sprintf` (some dont!), an alternative way to do it would be:

```
$test = str_pad(mt_rand(1, 999999),6,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Example output:

```
736523
024132
003145
```

Using `mt_rand` here because its a better random number function (not perfect, but better than just `rand`). Also adjusted to 999999 since 1000000 could possibly produce a 7 digit number.

---

Doing a benchmark of 10000 iterations on the three answers provided (Sean, Mine, Aslan), these are the results in speed:

```
Sean's Method:   0.005
My Method:       0.006
Aslan's Method:  0.009
```

So you would be better off going with Sean's method.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to using sprintf that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Thanks for your alternative method and pointing out 1000000 could return 7 digits!

Comment: @Vince0789 no disadvantage. Readability? Personal preference? Its subjective. I added a benchmark for speed concerns.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber I also benchmarked the difference between `rand` and `mt_rand` in the examples, and it seems `rand` slows things down. So if you went with `mt_rand` and Sean's answer, you would get the most performance for one line of code (of course we are talking micro-micro seconds lol so... YMMV).

Comment: I'll go for the combination in that case, those microseconds may add up. Thx for your research!